# Different subscripts for $\nabla$ operators while deriving force on system of many particles

Tags: classical-mechanics, notation, differentiation

Consider a system of 4 particles in an external conservative field. So force acting on each particle is derived from potential energy $U(x,y,z)$of the particle+field system:

Total (external) force on the system of four particles is then:
$$
 \overrightarrow {F_{tot}} = \overrightarrow {F_1}^{ext} +\overrightarrow {F_2}^{ext} + \overrightarrow {F_3}^{ext} + \overrightarrow{F_4}^{ext} = -\overrightarrow{\nabla_1}(U_1) - \overrightarrow{\nabla_2}(U_2) - \overrightarrow{\nabla_3}(U_3) - \overrightarrow{\nabla_4}(U_4)
$$

Why do we need different subscripts, namely 1, 2, 3 and 4, for $\nabla$ operators ?

It means, for example, $$ \overrightarrow{\nabla_1} = {\partial \over\partial x_1} \hat i + {\partial \over\partial y_1} \hat j + {\partial \over\partial z_1} \hat k$$

But each of $x_1,y_1,z_1$ can have all values from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$; same for $x_2,y_2,z_2,x_3,y_3,...z_4$

All the particles are moving in the **SAME** 3-dimensional space.

Comment: The field has a potential (energy per unit charge), say $V(x,y,z)$, a function of the space coordinates $x,y,z$ and in general of time $t$. A particle $P_{k}$ located at $\mathbf{r}_{k}=(x_{k},y_{k},z_{k})$ has potential energy $U_{k}(x_{k},y_{k},z_{k})=q_{k}\cdot V(x_{k},y_{k},z_{k})$ where $q$ the charge of the particle (for example electric in electromagnetic field or mass in gravitational field).

Comment: The field force on this particle is $\mathbf{F}_{k}=-q_{k}\cdot\left[\boldsymbol{\nabla}V(x,y,z)\right]_{\left(x=x_{k},y=y_{k},z=z_{k}\right)}$. So, you must find by partial differentiation the gradient of the potential   $\boldsymbol{\nabla}V(x,y,z)=\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial z}\right)$ as function of the variables $x,y,z$ and  then replace these variables by their values $x_{k},y_{k},z_{k}$ respectively.

Comment: @Frobenius: Thanks for comments. I got your point. Can we say like this also ? : Say particle no. 2 has occupied some $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ at some fixed time $t_0$. So remaining 3 particles can not occupy  location $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ at the same  time $t_0$. i.e. particle no. 2 can not occupy  $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ where $k = 1, 3, and 4$. And to distinguish the range of these space co-ordinates, we need to put subscripts on del operators.

Comment: I think that we must not use such a picture. It's already wrong to say that every particle $k$ has its own potential $U_{k}$ : it's like to say that there exist 4 fields, each field acting on one particle but not on the other 3. By the way my favorite Physicist is P.A.M. Dirac whose photo as child you use in your profile.

Comment: "The Strangest Man-The Hidden Life of Paul Dirac, Mystic of the Atom [Farmelo]" http://i.imgur.com/g3yJiWm.jpg

Comment: @Frobenius: If you see 1st chapter of famous book "classical mechanics" by Goldstein, you will find :

Comment: @Frobenius: (Please ignore above comment)..If you see 1st chapter of famous book "classical mechanics" by Goldstein, you will find : $\sum_i \int_1^2 F_i^{(e)}.ds_i = -\sum_i \int_1^2 \nabla_i V_i .ds_i = -\sum_i V_i|_1^2$ .......So does it not say that every particle k has its own potential $V_k$ ? If this equation in the book is wrong (in notation), then what will be the correct one ?

Comment: Using for every particle its own potential is a preparation to introduce the potentials of internal forces. Then each particle is under the potential of the external field plus the potential of the forces of the other particles. So every particle lives in "its own" potential. In case of an external field only  using "their own" potential is a little confusing. I think we must avoid now extended discussions in comments. Good Luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39001/discussion-between-atom-and-frobenius).